# WebAPI Modelbinding - [FromUri] not working on enumerations of Guids

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable, model-binding

I'm trying to build an RESTApi-endpoint where the users can send multiple ids to filter for specific resources.

Therefore I've created an request-object which can be reused inside my own project to keep things simple (at least for me).

When building the GET-calls QueryString, I check the request-ojects properties for beeing an `IEnumerable`. If so, I'll append the values as following:

```
var collection = new NameValueCollection();
foreach (var pi in request.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
{
    var propVal = pi.GetValue(request, null);
    if (propVal == null)
        continue;

    if (pi.PropertyType.IsArray || typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType))
    {
        var enumerable = propVal as IEnumerable;
        if (enumerable != null)
        {
            foreach (var singleValue in enumerable)
            {
                collection.Add(pi.Name, singleValue.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        collection.Add(pi.Name, propVal.ToString());
    }
}
return collection;
```

which will build me something like e.g.

> http://localhost/API/Reporting/EndPoint?Ids=b94a3f1b-15cd-4feb-ac34-bd58bc1c3c2b,77dc84ac-4d48-4cbd-ba12-9de3108a5747

The endpoint accepts the request-object building it from the uri using the `[FromUri]` attribute.

```
public TheResponse EndPoint([FromUri] TheRequest request)
```

whereas `TheRequest` has a property of type `IEnumerable<Guid> Ids {get;set;}`.

However, the Ids property is always an Empty array with an empty `Guid`.

How can this be achieved? Do I need custom model-binding here?

As requested, this is how my request-object looks like:

```
public class TheRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<Guid> Ids { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please add full TheRequest code.

Comment: It can be achieved with a custom model-binder.

Comment: @Nkosi could you provide a link where to start from or point me some direction on how the model-binder should be implemented?

Comment: @KingKerosin, start here [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 4):

Now I mocked up an integration test based on this situation. The default `[FromUri]` model binder is having issue binding `Guid`s as you currently have them in the query string because it is reading it as just one long string

> `94a3f1b-15cd-4feb-ac34-bd58bc1c3c2b,77dc84ac-4d48-4cbd-ba12-9de3108a5747`

Which it cannot parse to a valid `Guid`. Hence the collection with one empty `Guid` (`default(Guid)` or `Guid.Empty`).

But if the query string is provided like this:

> /API/Reporting/EndPoint?Ids=b94a3f1b-15cd-4feb-ac34-bd58bc1c3c2b&Ids=77dc84ac-4d48-4cbd-ba12-9de3108a5747

By separating them into individual parameters `?Ids={guid}&Ids={guid}` and test it, notice that the endpoint will be called with the correct parameters populated.

So either change how the URL is constructed or, if the current format cannot be changed, then make a custom model binder to interpret the query string as desired.

For the custom model binder start here [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)